# Find differences in file and sorting file by key

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, text-processing, diff

So I have two language files, english and french. They are in this format:

```
key=translation
```

An example in English would be:

```
ui.title=My Title
```

And in French:

```
ui.title=Mon Titre
```

So I need a script that reads the language files and finds the differences. So say that the English file had keys:

```
ui.title=Title
ui.close=Close
```

But French only had

```
ui.title=Mon Titre
```

After running the script, it should output a file `french.changes` containing `ui.close=Close`. So this way, I can send the file off to my translators and they can translate it.

When I get it back, I can simply run cat `french.changes >> french; sort -o Language_fr_FR.properties`, to merge the changes.

I also need a method of sorting the language files by the key not the whole line.

I looked into `diff` but not sure how to use it correctly. I have been using Linux for quite a while but not so up to speed on fancy scripting :)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Are all `key=translation` entries on separate lines? Apart from the missing lines, are all entries in the same order? Is the order of the lines of importance or could they be rearranged?

Comment: 1. I changed my mind, I want the output of the changes file to be like `ui.close=Close` rather than `ui.close=` so that people know what to translate. 2. Yes, they are all on separate lines. 3. The order of the lines in the `.changes` file doesn't have to be sorted, but the one after being merged back after translation should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

`grep -v -f <(sed -r 's/([^=]*).*$/\1/' fr.i18n.txt) en.i18n.txt`

Which filters all keys from fr.i18n.txt from en.i18n.txt.

Example:

```
$ cat > en.i18n.txt
ui.title=Title
ui.close=Close
ui.edit=Edit
ui.accept=Accept
^D
$ cat > fr.i18n.txt
ui.title=Titre
ui.edit=Modifier
^D
$ grep -v -f <(sed -r 's/([^=]*).*$/\1/' fr.i18n.txt) en.i18n.txt
ui.close=Close
ui.accept=Accept
$ FINISHED="$(grep -v -f <(sed -r 's/([^=]*).*$/\1/' fr.i18n.txt) en.i18n.txt)"
$ echo "$FINISHED"
ui.close=Close
ui.accept=Accept
```

@don_crissti also correctly pointed out, that in this case the filterlist can also easily by generated with `cut`tin the `1`st `f`ield using the `d`elimiter '=':

`grep -v -f <(cut -d= -f1 fr.i18n.txt) eng.i18n.txt`

Answer (score 5):

The following takes two files, eng and fr, sorts them on the key, and
"joins" them on the key, showing only any missing entries from file 1 (eng).

```
join -t= -v1 <(sort -t= -k 1,1 eng) <(sort -t= -k 1,1 fr)
```

So the sort on key you want is eg:

```
sort -t= -k 1,1 eng
```

Comment: Same thing here, a messed up, I want the output of the changes file to be like ui.close=Close rather than ui.close= so that people know what to translate. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Would this work with more parts of the key? I see 1.1, 2.2 etc and not sure if that is limiting it to only `*.*` and not allowing for a key of `x.y.z.a.b.c=Hello!`

Comment: `1.2` refers to field 2 of file 1, where the fields were split on "=", so the form of the key is not important.

Comment: `join -v1 -t= <(sort eng) <(sort fr)` is enough for `english field data`

Comment: @Costas great simplification, thanks. my notes on `join` from 10+ years ago need a refresh. I still needed to sort on the key only though, else join complains with my example data with keys of different lengths.